# Application of Union+Find algorithm(Disjoint Set)

Tags: java, algorithm, disjoint-sets, union-find

**Problem Statement:**

Equations are given in the format `A / B = k`, where `A` and `B` are variables represented as strings, and `k` is a real number (floating point number).

Given some queries, return the answers. If the answer does not exist, return -1.0.

Example: Given `a / b = 2.0, b / c = 3.0.`

queries are: `a / c = ?, b / a = ?, a / e = ?, a / a = ?, x / x = ?` 
return  `[6.0, 0.5, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0 ]`

The input is:

```
vector<pair<string, string>> equations
vector<double>& values
vector<pair<string, string>> queries
```

where `equations.size() == values.size()`, and the values are positive.

This represents the equations.

Return `vector<double>`.

According to the example above:
equations = `[ ["a", "b"], ["b", "c"] ]`

values = `[2.0, 3.0]`

queries = `[ ["a", "c"], ["b", "a"], ["a", "e"], ["a", "a"], ["x", "x"] ]`

The input is always valid. You may assume that evaluating the queries will result in no division by zero and there is no contradiction.

**Solution**
This can be solved using Union+Find on disjoint set, a solution is seen here:

[Solution](https://github.com/cherryljr/LeetCode/blob/master/Evaluate%20Division.java)

However, I'm not clear on the intuition behind line 59:

```
rst[i] = uf.rank.get(queries[i][0]) / uf.rank.get(queries[i][1]);
```

As well as line 99:

```
rank.put(aFather, quotient * rank.get(b) / rank.get(a));
```

Comment: Main idea here is to store(line 99) `xFather/a` and `xFather/b`, where `xFather` is common father for `a` and `b`. When you need `a/b` ratio, you just need to do `(xFather/b)/(xFather/a)`(line 59).

Comment: If there are no copyright concerns, you should paste the code here instead of pointing to github. This way if the code there changes, or gets deleted, this question would be unaffected and would still be coherent.

Answer (score 5):

It's not hard to follow what happens. Pretty clever in fact!

Let's take a more complex example:

```
a / b = 2.0, b / c = 3.0, c / d = 4.0, d / e = 5.0
```

During the first step (*MakeSet* triggered by `UnionFind uf = new UnionFind(set)`) each element is set to be its own parent, and all ranks are set to 1.0:

```
parent(a) = a, rank(a) = 1.0
...
parent(e) = e, rank(e) = 1.0
```

During the *Union* step, the rank of the node is set to the given quotient, while the rank of the parent stays the same (line 99). So after `union(a, b, 2.0) parent(a) = b, rank(a) = 2.0` and the invariant is maintained for any node n: `rank(n)/rank(parent(n)) = value`, where value is from the equation being processed (the `quotient` argument).
At the end we get:

```
parent(a) = b, rank(a) = 2.0
parent(b) = c, rank(b) = 3.0
parent(c) = d, rank(c) = 4.0
parent(d) = e, rank(d) = 5.0
parent(e) = e, rank(e) = 1.0
```

During the *Compress* step, if the parent of the node being searched is not the *representative node* of the set, then it is set to be by recursively searching for the parent of the parent of the parent... and setting the rank of the current node as the current rank multiplied by the rank of the parent (line 87). So in the end we arrive at:

```
parent(a) = e, rank(a) = 120.0
parent(b) = e, rank(b) = 60.0
parent(c) = e, rank(c) = 20.0
parent(d) = e, rank(d) = 5.0
parent(e) = e, rank(e) = 1.0
```

So indeed rank(a) = rank(b) * 2.0, rank(b) = rank(c) * 3.0 etc. just as given in the input equations.

Note that the *representative node* of a set (i.e. the ultimate parent, `e` in this example) always ends-up having a rank of 1.0. This is why repeatedly calling `compressedFind` and executing line 87 doesn't further change the rank of a node, once it's been computed and the parent been set.

Now it's easy to see how line 59 works: if the query is a / b then rank(a) / rank(b) = 120.0 / 60.0 = 2.0

Terminology used from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure